# _spin_unlock_irqrestore() has very high sampling rate in my kvm, why?

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm

I run a SPECJbb benchmark in my KVM virtual machine. It shows a drastic drop on throughput between Warehouse 2 and Warehouse 3(The different between them is just addding on cocurrent task)

Then I use perf in my guest virtual machine. It shows that _spin_unlock_irqrestore has very high sampling rate.

Events: 31K cycles

- 74.89%  [kernel]          [k] _spin_unlock_irqrestore
- 7.36%  perf-1968.map     [.] 0x7f84b913e064
- 6.82%  [kernel]          [k] __do_softirq
- 6.39%  [kernel]          [k] handle_IRQ_event

...

It seems that only 7.36% cpu time running my Java program. Why _spin_unlock_irqrestore's sampling rate is so high? And what does it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's bad reporting by `perf`, not cycles consumed by `_spin_unlock_irqrestore`.

When IRQs are disabled, perf's interrupts are not processed. Instead, they're processed when interrupts are re-enabled. When perf's interrupt handler looks at the instruction pointer, to see what code was running, it finds the function that enabled interrupts - quite often it's `_spin_unlock_irqrestore`.

So all you know is that the cycles were consumed by code that had interrupts disabled, and enabled them using `_spin_unlock_irqrestore`.

If you can get perf to use NMI (non maskable interrupt), it could solve this problem.
I know that it can be done with oprofile (perf's predecessor) by changing the makefile, but don't know about perf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me some more explain about why IRQ disabled time is so long? Is that because I run it in kvm? Thanks!